# How to change date format of this data structure in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have some users and the structure is something like that:

```
{
 "_id": {"$oid":"6213baaba013b7c5f1232e25"},
 "birthDate": 239290215000,
 "surname": "Yang",
 "name": "Ruby",
 "joinDate": 1534861815000,
 "children": [
    {
     "birthDate": 876749415000,
     "surname":"Yang",
     "name":"Bob"
    },
    {
     "birthDate":926753415000,
     "surname":"Yang",
     "name":"Mel",
     "joinDate":1579005015000
    }
 ],
}
```

I will calculate age of user and then how long ago did they join? So I've tried to change date format but I was only able to change the format of the parents' birth dates. I could not change the format of the children's birth dates. How can I change all dates and calculate their ages?
My expected output:

```
{
 "_id": {"$oid":"6213baaba013b7c5f1232e25"},
 "birthDate": ISODate(...),
 "surname": "Yang",
 "name": "Ruby",
 "joinDate": ISODate(...),
 "children": [
    {
     "birthDate": ISODate(...),
     "surname":"Yang",
     "name":"Bob"
    },
    {
     "birthDate": ISODate(...),
     "surname":"Yang",
     "name":"Mel",
     "joinDate": ISODate(...)
    }
 ],
}
```

Comment: please add a sample of your expected output

Comment: can you Please tell us about which technology (language) you are using and the code you are using to create this object

Comment: I do not create this object. In order to demonstrate some samples, I've created in MongoDBCompass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly you can try this:

The trick here is to use [$toDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/).

So, to output the values as `ISODate` instead of timestamp you can use this aggregate query with a `$map` to update every `children` object:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "birthDate": {
        "$toDate": "$birthDate"
      },
      "joinDate": {
        "$toDate": "$birthDate"
      },
      "children": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$children",
          "in": {
            "surname": "$$this.surname",
            "name": "$$this.name",
            "birthDate": {
              "$toDate": "$$this.birthDate"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sacNNyDfqKO)

Also, if you want to update the DB values, (not only output ISODate but also change values in DB) you can try this `update` query:

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      // the same $set as before
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/c2yd_zjgEZx)

Comment: This method solved my problem, thank you!

Comment: I've updated using [$toDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/) which is easier to read and implement.

Comment: This method is more understandable. Thank you again. If I use "update", I wouldn't overwrite existing data, would I?

Comment: Yes, using `update` documents are updated and overwrite. `aggregate` only show values without change data in the DB but `update` does.